# Module, register singleton service

Tags: prism

I would like to initialize my modules and add globally available services to the container.

I get the following error:

> - The exception message was: Methode nicht gefunden: "Void      Prism.Ioc.IContainerRegistryExtensions.RegisterSingleton(Prism.Ioc.IContainer  Registry)".

This is my code:

```
 public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ProjectNavigation>();
// This line throws
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IProjectService,    
    ProjectService>();}
```

Comment: Could you add the constructor for the class that implements the IProjectService interface?

Comment: Are your project's references correct? Looks like messed up dlls to me.

Comment: public class ProjectsModule : IModule
    {
        public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
        {
            var regionManager = containerProvider.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
            regionManager.Regions["Tabs"].Add(new ProjectTab());     
        }

        public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ProjectNavigation>();

            containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IProjectService, ProjectService>();
        }
    }

Comment: The first line works as expect, only the second line throws.

Comment: @ Rob Goodwin: The class that implemenst the IProjectService didn't have a constructor.